# How to replace a character that exists independently rather than with other characters in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, replace, character-replacement

Ok lets suppose i've got this string:

```
R RATS ARE FAR
```

I want to replace the independent R with an X so to make:

```
X RATS ARE FAR
```

I've tried stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString but that replaces all R's to X's. One way to accomplish it is to check if there's a space before and after the letter, which would mean its independent and then go for the kill, but this approach seems so lame. Also the string is dynamic and so are the position of R's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that words can be surrounded by just about any non-alphanumeric character, right? (Otherwise you'd just replace @" R " with " X ", plus special cases for leading/trailing occurrences)

---

One way to do it would be to use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/)'s

```
[string replaceOccurrencesOfRegex:@"\bR\b" withString:@"X"];
```

(`\b` denotes word **b**oundaries in PCRE-style regular expressions)

---

And then there is [CFStringTokenizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/Reference/reference.html) (search linked documentation for `kCFStringTokenizerUnitWordBoundary`), which might be of help, alternatively.

Comment: RegexKitLite worked awesome. Anyone else trying to do the same thing all you need to do is to add "The two files, RegexKitLite.h and RegexKitLite.m, and linking against the /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib ICU shared library." Plus the string to be replaced should be an NSMutableString and I had to use \\b instead of \b in the above example. And that did the trick for me. Thank you Regexident.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
NSString *statement = @"R RATS ARE FAR";
statement = [statement stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" R " withString:@" X "];
// now check if the string starts with R + space
if ([statement hasPrefix:@"R "])
    statement = [statement stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"R " withString:@"X " options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
// now check the end
if ([statement hasSuffix:@" R"])
   statement = [statement stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" R" withString:@" X" options:0 range:NSMakeRange([statement length] - 2, 2)];
```

And if you are planning to a lot of replacement in this string, you should use `NSMutableString`.

Comment: This is actually pretty much what I described, too. It has one big flaw though: This only works if the word sequence is a strictly space delimited word sequence. As soon as you introduce non-alphanumeric/non-space characters your method breaks, example: "FOO IS R, BAR IS NOT".

Comment: @Regexident, the original question doesn't mention anything about non-alpha character.

Comment: Fair point. The language-likeness of OP's sample string made me assume there could be other letters involved even if not mentioned specifically. Anyway, I'd still prefer to use an abstraction (here: regex) of the problem, though, rather than having code all possible edge cases yourself. Abstraction is more secure to minor format changes, hence has a longer lifetime, than single-purpose one-shot implementations. Would you agree? I'm curious.

Comment: All comments aside there's no doubt that you, too, provided a valid solution to OP's question. :)

Comment: I agree using Regex is a better solution. But if the original question is the complete scope, then I like my solution if I don't have to add another library to my project.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Regex should be part of the Foundation frameworks anyway. Can't wait for Lion to hopefully bring it, eventually. Have an upvote! :)

Comment: @Regexident, thanks. I am happy to meet people that knows, as the saying goes, "[there's more than one way to skin a cat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there's_more_than_one_way_to_skin_a_cat)."

Comment: Indeed, there are enough solutions for all of us! :P Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @Regexident, can you join the Objective-C chat room?